# Regex for looking for R in and document

Tags: regex

I have an email corpus. I need to find all the emails that have references to R (the statistical programming language) in it. R can appear at the start of the Sentence, in the middle on the end. E.g

1. **R** is a powerful programming language.
2. While building our system, **R** was installed.
3. Incorporated **R** in our application installer.
4. .... to reduce cost. **R** very popular among fresh graduates
5. .... data analysis using **R**.
6. The statistical programming language of choice, **R**, was a pre-requisite to the course.

I don't want the regex to match for e.g. **ROAR** or **R&D** etc.

How can I build such a Regex?

Comment: Is the formatting in 2. and 6. intended with the `**` before the commas, or should those just be bold like the rest? Basically you want to match just the letter `R` in uppercase preceded by a blank and followed by either a blank or punctuation, does that encompass all your relevant scenarios?

Comment: @Saqib Ali - I am sure there will already be answers for such basic question on SO :)

Comment: @Secespitus, sorry that was a type. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a simple regex like this `(\bR\b)[\s\n.,;?:-]`
This assumes "R" will always be in capital letters.

Comment: Wouldn't "\bR\b" also match R&D?

Comment: You are right, updated my answer, a safer approach would be add all known characters which can come just after word 'R' in the list (Square Brackets), as of now it assumes that 'R' (For R Programming) keyword will be followed any one of the following: space, newline, full stop, comma, semi-colon, question mark or a dash. You can add more to the list.

Comment: This will also match 'R' from R-Studio, but not 'R' from RStudio, also this can return some false positives for example 'R' from, R.K.